# Spam flag disputed and post rolled back

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, rollbacks, disputed-flags

Some months back I flagged a post as spam. The flag was disputed. I know *disputed* is not equal to *declined*. I've got many flags disputed, but this time I feel very bad about it. Why? Because I participated in last moderator election on Stack Overflow. Under my nomination someone posted a comment like:

> You say you have 500+ flags, but the stats say you have 452 helpful
>   flags. Does that mean >10% of your flags have been found invalid? –
>   Juhana Feb 14 at 19:34

So disputed votes also counts, that's why I asked this question.

Link to the question (it's now deleted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271077/unexpected-identifier-in-ajax-page-loader

Revision of the question that I flagged: [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11271077/2)

> [image: Spam Post]

But I'm pretty sure that the flag was correct, so why was it disputed? One moderator rolled back that spam question to its first revision. Is that the reason why the flag was disputed? If so, why can't the flag be approved before rolling back?

Comment: Why didn't you rollback yourself?

Comment: That doesn't qualify as spam...

Comment: Abcdefg isn't spam, its post vandalism.  Spam is "would you like to buy  ......"

Comment: Maybe we need a "defacement" flag then?

Comment: @RichardTingle: AFAIK for questions there is no flag like Vandalism. `Vandalism` flags comes for suggested edits

Comment: Yes, but you should roll back such vandalism rather than flagging at all

Comment: @RichardTingle: The same user asked the question and he made a edit like this, so do I need to rollback that ? Usually if a third person is doing such an edit and if it approves, I rollback that edit. But in this case, I thought it is better to flag. From next time onwards I'll do what you said, thanks :)

Comment: The OP licences the content to stack exchange, they aren't allowed to then destroy that content. You are fully within your rights to rollback (this usually happens with rage quiters or those hiding a homework question from their teachers

Comment: If I see self vandalized questions, I tend to rollback. Specially if there are answers. If you want to flag, use the "other" reason and explain it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you see a post vandalised like that and it's the first time, just do a rollback.

If the OP repeatedly vandalises his post(s), use the *other (needs ♦ moderator attention)* flag and explain the situation.

Answer (score 13):

The description of the spam flag:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

So even after that vandalism edit, the question did not qualify as spam. Spam flag means the post contains links which advertise something which is not useful or relevant to the site.

### What should I do in such situation?

If you have an edit privilege, just roll it back to the valid revision or suggest an edit. If the OP roll it back to the vandalism edit again then just flag it and explain the situation in "other" reason and request the moderator to lock the post.